# Cordova / Ionic sms receiver and parser

Tags: android, angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I have some problem with SMS parsing in my Cordova/Ionic app. I have no idea how to do it. Let me describe situation: First of all, I need to receive and read SMS from inbox. Secondly, I want to parse it. After that, I would like write data in local DB.

The SMS which I would like to parse from bank, and have 3 body pattern. For example:

```
1. MAES1111 07.05.16 09:49 deposits 0000.00R Total: 0000.00R <br>
2. MAES1111 07.05.16 10:15 writing off of amounts 0000.00R MAGAZIN DOMASHNIY Total: 0000.00R <br>
3. MAES1111 07.06.16 11:28 cash withdrawals 0000R ATM 215033 Total: 0000.00R
```

Where

1. `MAES` - Type of Card (VISA - visa,MAST- mastercard, MAES - maestro)
2. `1111` - 4 last symbols of Card Number;
3. `07.05.16` - date;
4. `10:15` - time;
5. `deposits` (writing off of amounts,cash withdrawals) - event with card such as crediting of money to the account and other;
6. After the event `0000.00R` - this is amount of the transaction;
7. `MAGAZIN` or `ATM 135151` - this is terminal or ATM code.
8. `Total: 0000.00R` - balance of account in this time after event.

Now my question is how can I parse SMS like this by JS, AngularJS and write the information in database SQLite local storage.

If in my table column is "Card Type and Card Number","Date" , "Event", "Amount of transection", "Total = balance of account", "tirminal or atm code"

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with cordova or Ionic. If I understand you correct you need to separate the data from the sms into something meaningful.  This is a job for one or more regular expression. If you don't know about regex that is what you need to look into.

Comment: Here is how you could separate the first part (\w{4})(\d{4})\s(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}) now you have carttype, last 4 digits, date and time separated.

Comment: iCediCe,  thanks a lot, you are cool man! I will use regex, and find some information about it and about separate the data.

Comment: iCediCe, Sorry for the stupid question i should use google as hard as i can .

Comment: No problem, glad that I could be of help check out http://www.regexpal.com for creating your regex... It even has a cheatsheet to help you out.